# Time complexity for finding minimum and maximum value of vector's elements in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory, notation

It's the code covering the above problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;
    int elementsOfVector;
    vector <double> wektor;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> elementsOfVector;
        wektor.push_back(elementsOfVector);
    }
    double min = wektor[0];
    double max = wektor[1];
    if (min > max) {
        min = wektor[1];
        max = wektor[0];
    }
        for(int i = 2; i<n; i++)    {
            if (max < wektor[i]) {
                max = wektor[i];
            }
            else if (min > wektor[i]) {
                min = wektor[i];
            }
        }
    cout << "Min " << min << " max " << max;
    return 0;
}
```

According to my analysis:
Firstly, we have a for loop to assign all vector's elements with values, we make n-iterations so the time complexity of the action is O(n). Then we have a if statement with condition within it where we compare one value to other but there are always just those two values no matter what n input is so we can assume it's O(1) constant complexity in Big-O notation - not sure if this is correct so I would be grateful If anyone could relate. In the second for loop we make n-2 iterations and the operations inside the for loop are simple arithmetic operations and cost 1 so we can avoid it in big O notation: To sum up n + n = 2*n O(2*n) so total time complexity is O(n). Am I right?

Comment: It's not that easy and surely not the answer to your homework. Consider `cin >> x`, for example, which you call in a loop but which you didn't include in your calculations.

Comment: You come to the right conclusion but the first sentence is nonsense. The time complexity of an algorithm does not take user input operations into account. What if the user doesn't feel like inputing anything? Then you hang forever and the time complexity makes no sense.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The question is asking about time complexity as a function of the size of the vector `n`. We can probably assume the time complexity of `cin >> x` is independent of `n`, so it can be considered constant in this case. Otherwise, it is meaningless to discuss time complexity as it is simply a function of how the user feels that day.

Comment: Your code will fail if there is just one element. You can initialize both `min` and `max` to `wektor[0]` and start from 1 without losing anything.

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt User input is a constant value - it's an integer that is greater than zero, it's a specific value like 5.

Comment: molbdnilo Thank you for point you've made - I will fix it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "User input is a constant value ...". I could make a guess where it would actually make sense, but guessing is bad. Being pedantic is important for getting correct and reliable results.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That's not helpful. Point is, you're assuming that `cin >> x` has a constant complexity. It is reasonable (you gave the reasoning), but it doesn't hurt stating those assumptions explicitly. If you do that for every operation there, you may find some that are not as simple to justify, like pushing into a vector.

Answer (score 0):

First part for loop. O(n)
Second part if(min>max) O(1)
Third part for loop O(n)

Total O(n)+O(1)+O(n) = O(n)
The third part since you iterator n-2 times, it's O(n).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it's O(n) + O(1) + O(n-2) = O(n)?

Comment: @AB Anything that's not growing as fast as the fastest growing summand can usually be ignored when considering the big-O notation. E.g. `O(n^3 + 99 * n^2 + 999999 * n + 999999) = O(n^3)`; it's the same for `O(n + (-2)) = O(n)`

Comment: @ You can basically ignore all addition, subtraction, multiplication and division by a real number when you calculate time complexity. The fastest one is the time complexity.   Some examples:  O(n+1000000000000000000000) = O(n);   O(n/100000000) = O(n);  O(n^3)+O(n^2)+O(n^1)+O(logn) = O(n^3) (only keep the fastest one).

Comment: Yes I know, just wanted to be more specific and make sure I understand all.